# Why isn't my condition working?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

In javascript, I'm making an HTML canvas game, and in that game I have an object type/constructor called gamePiece. gamePiece has a function called checkCollision:

```
    this.checkCollision = function(piece){
    var collisionX = piece.x >= this.x && piece.x <= (this.x + this.width);
    var collisionY = piece.y <= this.y && piece.y <= (this.y - this.height);
    if(collisionX || collisionY){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which is called by update()

```
    function update(){
context.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
for(var i = 0; i < gamePieces.length; i++){
    gamePieces[i].update();
    for(var mi = 0; mi < gamePieces.length; mi++){
        gamePieces[i].checkCollision(gamePieces[mi]);
        if(gamePieces[i].checkCollision(gamePieces[mi]) == true){
            gamePieces[i].collisionFunction();
        }
    }
}
}  
setInterval(function(){update();}, 1);
```

I have another object that is supposed to give a speed boost upon colliding with another game piece, and it logs every time it gives a speed boost.

```
   var speedBooster = new gamePiece(25,25,"red",300,300,0);
speedBooster.collisionFunction = function(){
    for(var whichpiece = 0; whichpiece < gamePieces.length; whichpiece++){
        if(speedBooster.checkCollision(gamePieces[whichpiece]) == true && gamePieces[whichpiece] != this){
            gamePieces[whichpiece].speed += 10;
            console.log("gamePieces[" + whichpiece + "] has been given a speed boost.");
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives a speed boost whenever a piece is behind it, and I put the "piece.x >= this.x &&" there for a reason. Why is JavaScript ignoring the condition I gave it?

Comment: Is 'x' and 'y' tracking the coordinates of the center of the object? If so, could the issue be that you are using the full width of the object from x and y, in the positive and negative direction respectively, rather than centering on the object. i.e. would something like this work?

    var collisionX = piece.x >= (this.x - this.width/2) && piece.x <= (this.x + this.width/2);
    var collisionY = piece.y <= (this.y - this.height/2) && piece.y <= (this.y + this.height/2);

Also, you should use '+' in (this.y - this.height).

Comment: thanks, but still produces ghost collisions

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var collisionX = piece.x >= this.x && piece.x <= (this.x + this.width);
var collisionY = piece.y >= this.y && piece.y <= (this.y + this.height);
if(collisionX && collisionY){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

To test if two objects overlap. Where the object has x,y as the top left and w,h as width and height

```
//Returns true if any part of box1 touches box2
function areaTouching(box1,box2){
     return ! (box1.x > box2.x + box2.w || 
               box1.x + box1.w < box2.x || 
               box1.y > box2.y + box2.h || 
               box1.y + box1.h < box2.y)
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that only considers if the object is in the exact x spot of the object, and I need it to happen when any parts of the objects touch

Comment: @C12 Have added example of test if boxes overlap